# explorer preview causes System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Automation rights are not granted. on ActivePresentation.name

Tags: c#, .net, com, vsto, powerpoint

```
public static PowerPoint.Presentation GetActivePPT(this PowerPoint.Application application)
{   
            try
            {
                if (App.Presentations.Count > 0)
                {
                    return application.ActivePresentation;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
}
```

I call this function like so:

```
PowerPoint.Presentation ppPresentation = PowerPointApplication.GetActivePPT();
if(ppPresentation != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ppPresentation.Name);
}
```

And I get a :

COMException: Message:Presentation (unknown member) : Invalid request.  Automation rights are not granted. StackTrace:    at Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Presentation.get_Name()

Here is what I know Presentations.Count is one and application.ActivePresentation is not null

It looks like I am not the only one to encounter this issue with Explorer preview:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/327cfc7b-07a3-49ad-9e0b-f7100852e3bf/applicationpresentationsopen-generating-exception-error-code-2147467259-automation-rights-are?forum=vsto
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e7437e44-1aea-4ab5-bbf2-6794037c872a/vsto-powerpoint-explorer-previewpane?forum=vsto
- http://youpresent.co.uk/presentations-count-returns-wrong-number/
- https://github.com/jon-hedgerows/msofficesvn/issues/25
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.powerpoint/KR1VuXtDccQ

It sounds like this is a permissions issue? hoping its as simple as setting something to COMVisible(true) but no good ideas at this point.

[this blog post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/17033990-f30b-47be-9095-1040d36875d1/applicationpresentationsopen-generating-exception-error-code-2147467259-automation-rights-are?forum=vsto) seems to claim a write lock is in play but Word and Excel do not exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: That's pretty special, never once seen it and no idea that this was possible at all.  The admin of those machines found an unusual way to make himself a Very Important Person.  You are going to have to talk to Him, best to bring frankincense and myrrh along.

Comment: Other than asking the son of God, whats my best course of action here?

Comment: As is mentioned in one of the links you included, if the presentation you intend to work with is being shown in Windows File Explorer's Preview pane, the file is open in a hidden instance of PowerPoint.  PowerPoint ordinarily allows only one instance of itself, so when there are two, one of which you're not allowed to automate, things get weird.  If you trap and ignore the error, it might be sufficient in some cases.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Their is only one instance of powerpoint and only one presentation. The issue is bigger than just blocking builtin  methods on the Presentation. I also have crashes accessing extension methods.

Comment: Just to be sure, you've looked at the Process List in Task Manager and ensured that there's only one instance of POWERPNT.EXE?  Otherwise you can't be sure that there's only one instance.

Comment: yep only one pid. Just to give some context, I have a feature thats kicks off on right click. I want the feature to still work for all embedded scenarios even if we are in a preview pane. So I don't want to work around the exception.

Comment: Short of trapping the error and killing the WinExplorer process, then trying again, I'm not sure how you'd do this, but please, if you find a workaround, post back here.  This ridiculous error is the bane of my existence.

Comment: Will do Steve! I have a feeling this is a COM interop issue. So my theory is If I move the section of code that retrieves the presentation to the unmanaged layer I maybe able to work around this issue.

Comment: So the Presentation.Container property seems interesting: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint._presentation.container(v=office.14).aspx "Returns the object that contains the specified embedded presentation. Read-only." seems like it can be used as an embedded ole check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you select a presentation in Windows Explorer with preview pane enabled, Windows Explorer appears to open the presentation in a hidden window.  If you attempt to access any of the hidden presentation's object members (e.g., `ppPresentation.Name`) from a COM add-in you get the "Automation rights are not granted." exception.

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a good way to determine if the hidden presentation was opened by Windows Explorer (e.g, `ppPresentation.Windows.Count = 0`), since accessing any of the presentation's object members via code seems to throw this exception.  Therefore, the only workaround appears to be error handling, like `Try/Catch`.

Note that `Presentations.Count` returns the number of *all* open presentations, including those opened by the preview pane, so you will need to account for this if your add-in relies on an accurate count of presentations it can actually work with.

Also, note that this problem does not appear to affect Excel in this same way.

Comment: It has been 2 months now and I have not found a work around. I had been trying to look up customXML data off of the presentation. without valid data my extension methods don't behave correctly.  I'll use your approach to alert the user as to what is going on and disable my plugin.