# How to know that a VSTO Word and Excel addin is being started by the Windows Explorer preview pane?

Tags: excel, ms-word, vsto

I have noticed that when users have the Windows file explorer preview pane enabled and then view a Word or Excel file, that my VSTO addin is started.  Further my addin starts again when the user double clicks on a excel or word file.

What properties in Word and Excel do I need to check at startup to know that it is the preview pane?

For people's reference I did find a discussion on this for [Powerpoint in this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601251/explorer-preview-causes-system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-automation)

Answer (score 2):

When Word and excel are started by the file explorer as a preview then what I have found is that you can check for a commandlinearg of -Embedding

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Contains("-Embedding"))
```

[Detecting Automation of Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106231/how-to-dected-excel-was-starting-by-automation-vsto-addin-context) is where I found this answer.  This question is about automation.

Also when a user embeds for example Excel in Word and then edits the embedded Excel the VSTO addin will start multiple times.  You can check for the -Embedding arg for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the ribbon bar is not visible when Office applications are used for rendering documents in the Windows explorer. You may use the following code to check that:

```
Application.CommandBars("Ribbon").Visible
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I have posted something that may be better.